# Como usar pseudo nomes com CONCAT e MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Uma questão sobre MySQL pede que o resultado saia nessa formato de resposta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao terminar minha solução através de uma consulta feita em **MySQL**, encontro o seguinte problema.

Abaixo um primeiro exemplo de solução da minha consulta que **Funciona**

`SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ' , COUNT(name),' ', occupation ) FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY occupation ORDER BY COUNT(name) ASC ;`

Abaixo um segundo exemplo de solução da minha consulta que **Não Funciona**

> SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ' , **COUNT(name) AS numb**,' ', occupation ) FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY occupation ORDER BY numb ASC ;`

O problema em questão é que eu gostaria de renomear o `COUNT(name)` para `numb` através de um '*aliase*' ou um pseudo nome, mas me deparo com esse erro.

```
ERROR 1583 (42000) at line 3: Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'
```

Seria possível contornar esse problema, ou seja, é possível o uso de pseudo nomes dentro da função `CONCAT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o standard não é possível usar aliases na mesma instrução de SELECT na qual eles são criados. Uma solução passa por usar um sub-query.

O standard informa que a sequência de execução das instruções é a seguinte:

```
1. FROM 
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY
7. TOP
```

O que explica, por exemplo, porque é que é possível utilizar um alias na cláusula ORDER BY.

Comment: Sempre que uso alguma função de agregação costumo dar nomes pra eles, nesse caso é para não repetir o "COUNT(name)" na  parte do GROUP BY.

Comment: Neste caso a solução passa por usar uma sub-query para calcular o total, após isto, poderá utilizar o alias tanto no SELECT como no GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível, e neste caso nem faz sentido. Imaginei inicialmente que iria usar o dado para mais alguma coisa, como não vai seria completamente desnecessário dar nome para o resultado da expressão usada na concatenação.

Não faz sentido não querer repetição porque a sintaxe pede a repetição.